# Proof of Cauchy-Goursat's Theorem using sub-triangles

Tags: complex-analysis

http://www.math.tamu.edu/~fnarc/psfiles/cauchygoursat.pdf

I was reading that article where the proof for Cauchy-Goursat's Theorem for a triangle domain $T$ was done by subdividing this triangle into 4 congruent sub-triangles $T_1,T_2,T_3,T_4$.
So we have
$$M=\int_{\partial T}f(z)dz = \int_{\partial T_1}f(z)dz+\int_{\partial T_2}f(z)dz+\int_{\partial T_2}f(z)dz+\int_{\partial T_4}f(z)dz$$

It then goes on to say that it can be seen for at least one triangle say $T_1$: 
$$\left|\int_{T_1}f(z)dz\right| \geq \frac{|M|}{4}.$$

I can't see why, even after applying the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just (ahem) the triangle inequality. Call the integrals $I_1,\ldots I_4$. One has $I_1+\cdots+I_4=M$. If $|I_j|<|M|/4$ for all $j$, then
$$|M|=|I_1+\cdots+I_4|\le |I_1|+\cdots+|I_4|<|M|.$$